# strcmp error: passing argument 2 of 'strcmp' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have the following code for which I try to access the field city of the type tHotel, and compare it with the a variable "city" defined before. 
However, I keep getting a (passing argument 2 of 'strcmp' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]) error. Any ideas?

```
#define MAX_BRAND 15+1
#define MAX_NAME 15+1
#define MAX_CITY 15+1
#define MAX_HOTELS 100
#define MAX_LINE 514

typedef enum {FALSE, TRUE} tBoolean;
typedef enum { BUDGET, INN, RESORT, CONDO, LUXURY, COUNTRY } tTypeHotel; 

typedef struct {
    int id; 
    char brand[MAX_BRAND]; 
    char name[MAX_NAME]; 
    char city[MAX_CITY]; 
    int category;
    tTypeHotel type;
    int numRooms;
    float priceDouble; /* reference price: double room */
    float distanceFromCityCenter;
    tBoolean hasPool;
    tBoolean hasGym;
    tBoolean closeToSubway;
    float percentOccupation;
} tHotel;

typedef struct {
    tHotel hotels[MAX_HOTELS];
    int nHotels;
} tHotelTable;


void hotelsTableSelect (tHotelTable hotelsTable, char city, float price, float distance, int points, tHotelTable *selectedHotelsTable){
    int numHotels;
    for (numHotels = 0; numHotels<=hotelsTable.nHotels;++numHotels){
        if (strcmp(hotelsTable.hotels[numHotels].city,city)==0){
            //-------
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: change `char city` to `char *city` in the function argument list, then be sure to call the function with a pointer in that position.

Comment: What part of the error message didn't you understand? Maybe we can help explain.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`void hotelsTableSelect (tHotelTable hotelsTable, char *city, float price, float distance, int points, tHotelTable *selectedHotelsTable)`

`city` is `char` not `char *`